# Best practice for very large if-else-statement using LLVMs RTTI system

Tags: c++, llvm, rtti, llvm-c++-api

I am currently writing a piece of software that relies on another library, which makes heavy use of LLVMs RTTI system. I cannot change the API of said library and it forces me to implement very large if-else-statements over several types and their sub-types. Usually I would have used at a switch-statement instead, but that is obviously not possible using LLVM's *dyn_cast<>()*.

Below is an example of what I am currently doing, however, this turned out to be a real bottleneck. Are there any better ways of achieving the same, but with less overhead?

Thanks a ton!

```
 if (const SomeClass *casted = dyn_cast<SomeClass>(something))
 {
     ...
 }

 else if (const anotherClass *casted = dyn_cast<AnotherClass>(something))
 {
     ...
 }

 ...

 else
 {
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch([something->getType()->getTypeId()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Type.html#ac7b0ed5c6d30bad74769c6e87ab0edb8)) sometimes, but some dyn_cast<>() calls will probably be unavoidable, e.g. for struct types you define.

Comment: Can't you `static_cast` if you already know to have the correct type? Not sure how llvm's `dyn_cast` worked.

Comment: @arnt Ah sorry, I see now how my example might be a bit confusing. I wasn't referring to llvm::Type objects, but rather classes defined by the library that implement the LLVM RTTI system. Unfortunately, these don't have any member variable that would allow for a switch case statement. will edit the example for clarity. But thanks for the idea!

Comment: @bitmask The LLVM RTTI system works separately from that of C++ and as far as I know there is no such thing as a *static_cast*. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @LorenzH. Ah yes, my llvm is super rusty.

Comment: dyn_cast<> and getTypeId() use the same mechanism, IIRC. I might be rusty, but I don't think it's possible to provide the capability to use dyn_cast without also providing the capability to switch on typeid.

Comment: Okay, so after some more digging I found that the answer given by @arnt should in theory be correct. However, the library I am using, simply does not adhere to the LLVM API.

Comment: I will still mark this answer as correct, as it should be. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Reffereing [LLVM Programmers Manual](https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates). InstVisitor is recommended in such scenarios.

> Note that the dyn_cast<> operator, like C++’s dynamic_cast<> or Java’s instanceof operator, can be abused. In particular, you should not use big chained if/then/else blocks to check for lots of different variants of classes. If you find yourself wanting to do this, it is much cleaner and more efficient to use the InstVisitor class to dispatch over the instruction type directly.